# How to Get Data from AutoComplete Text View on Button Press?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to use the if-else statement on Button press - if-else statement get the string from autoComplete text view... but it not works...

I want to make the calculation when selecting the first product - but it does not work.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputLayout textInputLayout,alkalinityInput,waterVoume;
    TextInputEditText waterText,alkaText;
    TextView result;
    AutoCompleteTextView dropDownText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        waterVoume=findViewById(R.id.waterVolumeInputText);
        textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.productTextDropdown);
        dropDownText = findViewById(R.id.dropdown_text);
        alkalinityInput = findViewById(R.id.alkalinityInputText);
        waterText = findViewById(R.id.waterVtext);
        alkaText = findViewById(R.id.alkaVtext);
        result=findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

        String[] items = new String[] {
                "AquaForest - KH Plus",
                "Brightwell - Reef Code B",


        };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.dropdown_item,
                items
        );
        dropDownText.setAdapter(adapter);


        button=findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(dropDownText.getText().equals("AquaForest - KH Plus"))

                    {makeCalculations();
}

            }

            private void makeCalculations() {

                double vouumeValue = Double.valueOf(waterText.getText().toString());
                double alkvalue = Double.valueOf(alkaText.getText().toString());
                


                double resultView = 1*vouumeValue*alkvalue;
                result.setText("The result is: " + resultView );
                double resultView = 5*vouumeValue*alkvalue;
                result.setText("The result is: " + resultView );}*/
});




    }
}
```